# Trying to find the number of logical statements in a file

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm reading a file and I need to count the number of logical operators in that file, from suggestions on here I've tried using Regular expressions, but the one that I am using :

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"/and|x?or|&&|[<>!=]=|[<>&!]|\|{1,2}/gi");
```

returns everything that matches, for example it returns any variable with an `"or"` in it, or if I have a `"<="` operator it counts it as two separate operators ("<" and `"="` separately).

Should I even use regex at this point because it doesn't seem like it would help my situation.

Comment: I would ditch the regex and use the Microsoft Compiler Services (Rosyln) to parse and locate the SyntaxKind and SyntaxTokens you are interested in. It is not trivial to learn but I doubt you'll ever get it perfect with regex. [Here's an article](https://medium.com/@CPP_Coder/introduction-to-roslyn-and-its-use-in-program-development-bce2043fc45d)

Comment: It seems your regex counts `<=` once. the only thing your regex does not currently handle is boundary words for example it should not match `andd` but it should match `and0x3`. you can do this for that part of regex `(?<=\d|\b)(and|x?or)(?=\d|\b)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary could you also exclude hits in comments?

Comment: @Crowcoder Or inside literal strings.

Comment: seems hard to achieve with regex. especially if you want to consider `/* ... */` type of comments.

Answer (score 0):

In order to match `<=` and not `<` is to use conditional expression:

```
(<=|<|>=|>)
```

which will first try to match `<=` first and if it succeeds, it won't check for `<`.
Same applies to `>=` and `=`.

To match `or`, but not in words, you can use lookarounds to ensure that it is on it's own (adding this pattern to above):

```
(<=|<|>=|>|(?<=[^a-zA-Z])or(?=[^a-zA-Z]))
```

Try [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZwCIb/1).

Comment: What if he has these characters (like `<`, `=`, etc.) inside literal strings or comments? To me, using Regex to parse source code is the same [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) approach as using [Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/107625).